# Obtener la suma mayor de una matriz

Tags: java

Quiero encontrar n numeros que hagan la suma mas mayor, siendo n == numero de filas de la matriz, los numero que hagan la suma pueden ser repetidos, pero mi codigo actual solo funciona con numeros que no sean repitentes.

```
public int encontrarMayorSuma(int[][] matrix) {
        int suma = 0;
        String mayores = "";
        int mayor = -1;

        int n=matrix.length;
        while (mayores.length()<matrix.length) {
            mayor=obtenerMayor(matrix, mayores);
            mayores+=mayor;
        }
        System.out.println("SUMA de los mayores: " + mayores);

        return maxSum;

    }

    public int obtenerMayor(int[][] matrix, String mayores) {
        int mayor = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {

                if (matrix[i][j] > mayor && (mayores.indexOf(matrix[i][j] + "") == -1)) {
                    mayor = matrix[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return mayor;
    }
```

hago la prueba con esta matriz:

```
int[][] matriz = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 7, 9}};
```

o con esta matriz

```
int[][] matriz = {{1, 2, 3}, {7, 5, 6}, {1, 7, 9}};
```

obtengo `9 7 6` pero yo quiero obtener `9 7 7` ya que se permite numeros repitentes.

Comment: Mete todos los valores de la matriz en un `arraylist`, ordena el arraylist de mayor a menor y de ahí coges los tres primero valores del list

Comment: ¿Podrías aclarar un poco más lo que necesitas? Eso de ***la suma más mayor*** me desconcierta, está mal dicho. Se dice: **la suma mayor**. Luego está la parte (que tampoco es clara) sobre la cantidad de números. Pides *n* números, donde *n* es el número de filas de tu matriz, además los números pueden repetirse, ¿de dónde sacarás esos números? ¿De toda la matriz? Porque al parecer en tu ejemplo los sacas de cada fila, incluso si pueden repetirse como indicas, pones que los números son `9 7 7` que sumados dan `23`, pero si pueden repetirse, ¿porqué no escoges `9 9 9`? Es que no queda claro nada

Comment: agrega los valores de entradas, lo que te devuelve y lo que esperas que te devuelva

Comment: @MauricioContreras no podria ser 999 porque solo existe un solo 9, mientras que el numero 7 existe en dos posiciones

Comment: Entonces no hables de repetir. De la forma que lo planteas ahora, cada número en tu matriz es una entidad diferenciada. Lo que quieres hallar el es top *n* de los números de tu matriz. Ese es el planteamiento. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Creo que ya entendí que quieres hacer, así que te pondré dos formas de hacerlo, primero con streams:

```
package suma.mas.mayor;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class SumaMasMayor {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matriz = {{1, 2, 3}, {7, 5, 6}, {1, 7, 9}}; 
        int[] mayores = SumaMasMayor.mayores(matriz);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mayores));
    }

    private static int[] mayores(int[][] matriz) {
        int n= matriz.length; // filas
        return Arrays.stream(matriz).flatMapToInt(arr->Arrays.stream(arr)) // sacamos los numeros
                .map(i -> -i).sorted().map(i -> -i) // ordenamos en orden inverso
                .limit(n) // obtenemos solo n
                .toArray(); // los ponemos en un arreglo
    }

}
```

El truco de

```
.map(i -> -i).sorted().map(i -> -i)
```

es debido a que para un `IntStream` no le puedes pasar un lambda para ordenarlo

posteriormente con ciclos tradicionales:

```
package suma.mas.mayor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class SumaMasMayor {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matriz = {{1, 2, 3}, {7, 5, 6}, {1, 7, 9}};
        int[] mayores = SumaMasMayor.mayores(matriz);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mayores));
    }

    private static int[] mayores(int[][] matriz) {
        int n = matriz.length; // filas
        int[] result = new int[n]; // el resultado tendrá solo n elementos
        List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>(n); // por lo menos va a tener n elementos
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
                elements.add(matriz[i][j]); // extraemos los numeros a una colección
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(elements, Comparator.reverseOrder()); // ordenamos todos los números

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            result[i] = elements.get(i); // obtenemos los n elementos y los ponemos en el arreglo
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Si no te gusta usar índices puedes hacer los ciclos de llenado de la colacción de la siguiente manera:

```
    for (int[] numeros : matriz) {
        for (int numero : numeros) {
            elements.add(numero);
        }
    }
```