# Obtener la variable b que esta dentro del closure

Tags: javascript

Se puede obtener la variable `b`?

```js
let a = function() {
  const b = 20;
}

console.log(a().b);
```

Comment: `int` no es un identificador de variable válido en JS

Comment: Hola @noseJ revisa la respuesta de Alejandro Hernandez!

Comment: Ahí no hay una "closure" propiamente, te recomiendo leer [qué es una clausura](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/607/c%c3%b3mo-funcionan-las-clausuras-en-javascript/236263#236263)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te respondieron ya varios pero complementando, si quieres usar forzosamente la notación que pusiste `a().b` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
function a() {
  return {b: 20}
}
console.log(a().b)
```

o usando ES6

```js
 let a = () => ({b: 20})
    console.log(a().b)
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta @AlejandroHernandez, edité un poco tu respuesta, te invito a realizar el [tour] del sitio, saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes declarar una variable "global", que será modificada con el valor de `b` al llamar la función `a`:

```js
var globalVariable;

let a = function() {
  const b = 20;
  globalVariable = b;
}

a();
console.log(globalVariable);
```

También podrías retornar el valor de `b` al llamar la función:

```js
let a = function() {
  const b = 20;
  return b;
}

a();
console.log(a());
```

Comment: me ayudas con este porfavor https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/273307/suma-mas-mayor-de-una-matriz

Answer (score 1):

Debería bastar con que retornes el valor; es decir que tu código quede de este modo:

```js
    let a = function() {
      const b = 20;
      return b
    }
    
    console.log(a())
```

- Estas declarando dentro del ámbito de la funcion una variable pero no estas retornándola
- Imprime la variable `a` que al estar igualada con la función  puede acceder al valor que esta regresa, escribiendolo así: `a()`

Comment: con return es en el tiempo de ejecucion, no se puede de otra manera?

Comment: ¿cuál es el problema con obtener la variable cuando el programa se ejecuta, @noseJ?

Comment: solo simple curiosidad

Comment: @noseJ para entrar al chat solo necesitas 20, entonces ya puedes hacerlo; los 50 puntos son para dejar comentarios en las publicaciones.

Comment: me ayudas con esto porfavor https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/273307/suma-mas-mayor-de-una-matriz

Comment: un clousure retorna una funcion para ser ejecutada, si es asi no seria un clousure

Comment: Cierto @JackNavaRow además le he indicado al OP revise y analice las respuestas dadas para que verifique cuál marcar como aceptada

Answer (score 1):

Podemos obtener el código fuente de una función con el método `toString`. Podríamos acceder al valor de la variable `b` usando una expresión regular.
Gracias a esto, podríamos acceder al valor de la variable sin ejecutar el código devolviendo el valor de la variable, ni usando variables globales. Técnicamente **no obtienes la variable**, pero si puedes obtener su valor.

Si queremos obtener el valor de la variable desde fuera del entorno de ejecución (por ejemplo, desde otro archivo), podríamos leer el archivo fuente y aplicar una expresión regular.

¿Para qué lo quiere? Realmente no debería importarnos. Si es por curiosidad, aquí tienes la demostración usando el método `toString`.

```js
let a = function() {
  const b = 20;
}

// Con el método `toString` accedemos al código fuente
//   de la función
var codigoFuenteDeFuncion = a.toString();

// Aplicamos una expresión regular para obtener el valor
//   de la variable
var valorDeVariableInterna = /const\sb\s\=\s(.+);/.exec(codigoFuenteDeFuncion)[1];

console.log(valorDeVariableInterna);
```

Answer (score 0):

La manera en como quieres obtener la variable es incorrecta ya que quieres igualar una variable (por el int que lleva delante imagino que deseas que sea entera aunque esa declaración también es incorrecta) con una función.

Lo que debes hace es declarar una variable por ejemplo de esta forma:

```
var a;
```

Por otro lado si quieres que la función te devuelva un entero debemos decirle que lo haga agregándole el **return** y un nombre para asi poder llamarla y darle la equivalencia a nuestra variable inicial, en otras palabras, una forma de expresar lo explicado sería:

```
var a = retornar();

function retornar() {
  var b = 20;
  return b;
}

console.log(a);
console.log(retornar()); // esta sería otra forma
```